# HowTo: Force AntiAliased Fonts Symbian S60 3rd Edition Feature Pack 1

Tags: symbian, anti-aliasing, s60

Any ideas on how to force antialiased fonts on Symbian S60 3.1 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the best Solution here: [symbian-guru.com](http://www.symbian-guru.com/welcome/2009/08/how-to-change-fonts-on-your-symbian-phone.html)       *****